# CountdownTimer causes crash

Tags: android, android-progressbar, countdowntimer, android-homebutton

My CountdownTimer causes a crash of the operating system Android, when I push the home button and leave my app.
It does not happen with every cell phone and with every version of android. 
There is no Exception shown in Logcat.
Here is my code:

```
    ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar1);
    progressbar.setMax(100000);  

    /* ------------- BEGINNING: CountDown */

    final TextView myCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mycounter);
    counter = new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {  

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {  

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(zeitspiel.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_zeitspiel);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setTitle("Dialog");

    /* More stuff regarding the dialog... */

    dialog.show();  
    myCounter.setText("Ende!");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    myCounter.setText("Verbleibende Zeit: " + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000) + " Sek.");
    pBarCounter = (int)millisUntilFinished;
    }

   }.start();  
   /* ------------- ENDING CountDown */

   /* ------------- BEGINNING: Progressbar */
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
   ProgressBar progressbar1 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar1);

   while(pBarCounter <= 100000){  
   progressbar1.setProgress(pBarCounter);
   }
   } }).start();
   /* ------------- ENDING of Progressbar */
```

I have tried to disable the home key to "solve" the problem - it works fine, but the problem is that this sollution is not supported by Android 4.x and causes an exception. So this sollution is not practicable.

```
   @Override
   public void onAttachedToWindow() {
   this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
   super.onAttachedToWindow();
   }
```

Logcat:

```
09-17 16:19:45.466: I/ActivityManager(272): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=de.toropi.test.plus/.MainActivity bnds=[160,150][240,250]} from pid 482
09-17 16:19:45.546: D/dalvikvm(2115): Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-17 16:19:45.546: I/ActivityManager(272): Start proc de.toropi.test.plus for activity de.toropi.test.plus/.MainActivity: pid=2115 uid=10027 gids={}
09-17 16:19:45.596: W/ResourceType(272): Skipping entry 0x7f04002a in package table 0 because it is not complex!
09-17 16:19:45.596: W/ResourceType(272): Skipping entry 0x7f04003d in package table 0 because it is not complex!
09-17 16:19:45.666: D/TextLayoutCache(2115): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
09-17 16:19:45.716: D/libEGL(2115): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
09-17 16:19:45.716: D/libEGL(2115): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
09-17 16:19:45.716: D/libEGL(2115): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
09-17 16:19:45.726: D/libEGL(2115): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
09-17 16:19:45.756: D/OpenGLRenderer(2115): Enabling debug mode 0
09-17 16:19:45.866: I/ActivityManager(272): Displayed de.toropi.test.plus/.MainActivity: +330ms
09-17 16:19:47.656: I/ActivityManager(272): START {cmp=de.toropi.test.plus/.hauptmenue} from pid 2115
09-17 16:19:47.706: D/dalvikvm(2115): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 153K, 4% free 6525K/6791K, paused 16ms
09-17 16:19:47.716: I/dalvikvm-heap(2115): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.794MB for 371216-byte allocation
09-17 16:19:47.746: D/dalvikvm(2115): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 6886K/7175K, paused 14ms
09-17 16:19:48.116: D/dalvikvm(2115): GC_CONCURRENT freed 567K, 10% free 6730K/7431K, paused 297ms+1ms
09-17 16:19:48.206: D/dalvikvm(2115): GC_CONCURRENT freed 342K, 8% free 6877K/7431K, paused 1ms+2ms
09-17 16:19:48.296: D/dalvikvm(2115): GC_CONCURRENT freed 389K, 7% free 6940K/7431K, paused 1ms+2ms
09-17 16:19:48.476: I/ActivityManager(272): Displayed de.toropi.test.plus/.hauptmenue: +810ms
09-17 16:19:48.486: D/OpenGLRenderer(2115): Flushing caches (mode 0)
09-17 16:19:50.286: I/ActivityManager(272): START {cmp=de.toropi.test.plus/.allgemeinwissen} from pid 2115
09-17 16:19:50.486: D/dalvikvm(2115): GC_CONCURRENT freed 240K, 5% free 7134K/7495K, paused 2ms+3ms
09-17 16:19:50.555: I/ActivityManager(272): Displayed de.toropi.test.plus/.allgemeinwissen: +236ms
09-17 16:19:50.566: D/OpenGLRenderer(2115): Flushing caches (mode 0)
09-17 16:19:52.246: I/ActivityManager(272): START {cmp=de.toropi.test.plus/.allgemeinwissen_pro} from pid 2115
09-17 16:19:52.686: I/ActivityManager(272): Displayed de.toropi.test.plus/.allgemeinwissen_pro: +423ms
09-17 16:19:52.696: D/OpenGLRenderer(2115): Flushing caches (mode 0)
09-17 16:20:02.055: I/ActivityManager(272): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.sonyericsson.home/.HomeActivity} from pid 272
09-17 16:20:02.126: D/OpenGLRenderer(2115): Flushing caches (mode 0)
09-17 16:20:02.166: D/OpenGLRenderer(2115): Flushing caches (mode 1)
09-17 16:20:07.546: D/dalvikvm(482): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1007K, 17% free 9990K/11911K, paused 27ms
09-17 16:20:13.386: D/lights(272): set_light_buttons: brightness=0
09-17 16:20:15.346: D/dalvikvm(1282): GC_CONCURRENT freed 354K, 8% free 6813K/7367K, paused 2ms+2ms
09-17 16:20:16.086: D/dalvikvm(1282): GC_CONCURRENT freed 500K, 9% free 6734K/7367K, paused 2ms+2ms
09-17 16:20:17.456: I/dalvikvm(482): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
09-17 16:20:18.326: I/ActivityManager(272): START {act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.marcow.birthdaylist/.MainActivity bnds=[2,166][318,234]} from pid -1
09-17 16:20:18.386: I/ActivityManager(272): Start proc com.marcow.birthdaylist for activity com.marcow.birthdaylist/.MainActivity: pid=2137 uid=10122 gids={}
09-17 16:20:18.396: I/dalvikvm(2137): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
09-17 16:20:18.476: W/Resources(2137): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f060097}
09-17 16:20:18.526: V/PhoneStatusBar(349): setLightsOn(true)
09-17 16:20:18.536: D/TextLayoutCache(2137): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
09-17 16:20:18.626: I/ActivityManager(272): Displayed com.marcow.birthdaylist/.MainActivity: +247ms
09-17 16:20:18.626: I/dalvikvm(272): Jit: resizing JitTable from 8192 to 16384
09-17 16:20:39.476: D/dalvikvm(272): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1050K, 18% free 11926K/14535K, paused 3ms+7ms

09-17 16:21:08.966: I/ActivityManager(272): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.sonyericsson.home/.HomeActivity} from pid 272
09-17 16:21:09.016: D/dalvikvm(2137): GC_EXPLICIT freed 200K, 5% free 6618K/6919K, paused 2ms+2ms
09-17 16:21:09.055: W/InputManagerService(272): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2c1358e0
09-17 16:21:13.156: D/dalvikvm(482): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 425K, 12% free 10522K/11911K, paused 57ms
09-17 16:21:14.386: D/dalvikvm(1969): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 7% free 7530K/8071K, paused 2ms+13ms
09-17 16:21:17.636: D/dalvikvm(1282): GC_CONCURRENT freed 391K, 8% free 6818K/7367K, paused 2ms+2ms
09-17 16:21:18.126: D/dalvikvm(1282): GC_CONCURRENT freed 526K, 9% free 6738K/7367K, paused 1ms+7ms
09-17 16:21:19.555: I/ActivityManager(272): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.radioopt.widget/com.tm.monitoring.Main bnds=[236,242][310,322]} from pid 482
09-17 16:21:19.626: W/ResourceType(272): Skipping entry 0x7f040033 in package table 0 because it is not complex!
09-17 16:21:19.636: W/ResourceType(272): Skipping entry 0x7f04003d in package table 0 because it is not complex!
09-17 16:21:25.436: D/lights(272): set_light_buttons: brightness=0
09-17 16:21:31.136: D/kernel(135): [  274.770233] bq27520 0-0055: bq27520_handle_soc_worker() capacity=43 (43) flags=0x138 ctrl_status=0x28d soh_state=0x1, valid=1
09-17 16:21:33.526: W/ActivityManager(272): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{2c1bb9f8 com.android.sonyericsson.android.server.dormant.fastdormancymanager} - receiver=android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver@2c1a0bc8, started 10006ms ago
09-17 16:21:33.526: W/ActivityManager(272): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{2bfb9748 ReceiverList{2bf75e20 272 system/1000 local:2c1a0bc8}}
09-17 16:21:40.696: I/InputDispatcher(272): Dropped event because it is stale.
09-17 16:21:40.696: I/InputDispatcher(272): Dropped event because it is stale.
09-17 16:21:40.696: I/InputDispatcher(272): Dropped event because it is stale.
09-17 16:21:40.696: I/InputDispatcher(272): Dropped event because it is stale.
09-17 16:21:40.696: I/InputDispatcher(272): Dropped event because it is stale.
09-17 16:21:40.696: I/InputDispatcher(272): Dropped event because it is stale.
09-17 16:21:40.696: I/InputDispatcher(272): Dropped event because it is stale.
09-17 16:21:40.696: I/InputDispatcher(272): Dropped event because it is stale.
09-17 16:21:40.696: I/InputDispatcher(272): Dropped event because it is stale.
09-17 16:21:40.696: I/InputDispatcher(272): Dropped event because it is stale.
09-17 16:21:40.716: I/InputDispatcher(272): Dropped event because it is stale.

09-17 16:22:04.926: I/power(272): *** set_screen_state 0
09-17 16:22:04.936: D/DASH - select(272): sensors_select_callback: select canceled by request
09-17 16:22:04.936: D/DASH - select(272): sensors_select_callback: select canceled by request
09-17 16:22:04.936: D/DASH-bma250_input(272): bma250_input_config_delay: rate:66667000
09-17 16:22:04.956: D/kernel(135): [  308.576141] request_suspend_state: sleep (0->3) at 304938997887 (2012-09-17 14:22:04.934997582 UTC)
09-17 16:22:04.956: D/kernel(135): [  308.576599] as3676 0-0040: as3676_early_suspend
09-17 16:22:04.956: D/kernel(135): [  308.579101] cyttsp-spi spi0.0: cyttsp_suspend: Enter
09-17 16:22:04.966: D/SurfaceFlinger(126): About to give-up screen, flinger = 0xfc48
09-17 16:22:05.126: W/kernel(135): [  308.757202] mddi_sony_ic_off_panel_off [3]
09-17 16:22:05.126: W/kernel(135): [  308.757202] sony_lcd_display_off [3]
09-17 16:22:05.176: W/kernel(135): [  308.812835] sony_lcd_dbc_off [3]
09-17 16:22:05.176: W/kernel(135): [  308.812835] dbc_ctrl = 1
09-17 16:22:05.176: W/kernel(135): [  308.812896] sony_lcd_enter_sleep [3]
09-17 16:22:05.305: W/kernel(135): [  308.938903] sony_lcd_enter_deepstandby [3]
09-17 16:22:10.006: W/ActivityManager(272): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{2c1aedf0 android.intent.action.TIME_TICK} - receiver=android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver@2bf162a0, started 10006ms ago
09-17 16:22:10.006: W/ActivityManager(272): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{2bf164a8 ReceiverList{2bf16430 272 system/1000 local:2bf162a0}}
09-17 16:22:16.206: D/dalvikvm(455): GC_CONCURRENT freed 868K, 10% free 9231K/10183K, paused 2ms+3ms
09-17 16:22:20.006: W/ActivityManager(272): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{2c1aedf0 android.intent.action.TIME_TICK} - receiver=android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver@2bf19698, started 10000ms ago
09-17 16:22:20.006: W/ActivityManager(272): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{2bf19910 ReceiverList{2bf19898 272 system/1000 local:2bf19698}}
09-17 16:22:30.026: W/ActivityManager(272): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{2c0b4468 android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF} - receiver=android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver@2bedd1e0, started 10002ms ago
09-17 16:22:30.026: W/ActivityManager(272): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{2bedd3c0 ReceiverList{2bedd348 272 system/1000 local:2bedd1e0}}
09-17 16:22:40.036: W/ActivityManager(272): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{2c0b4468 android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF} - receiver=android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver@2bc19590, started 10003ms ago
09-17 16:22:40.036: W/ActivityManager(272): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{2bc16668 ReceiverList{2bc17820 272 system/1000 local:2bc19590}}
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: please add you logcat for the crash

Comment: there is no crash in this logcat

Comment: I know. Thats why I wrote "There is no Exception shown in Logcat." But the cell phone has black screen and no button works. It is a mystery. Maybe a problem of the cell phone? But: It is my own cell phone and I never had problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions of Android has finally eradicated the misuse of home-key by marking a window as KeyGuard. Therefore, I believe you are out of luck in this issue. Perhaps you should consider changing your app design to follow the standard implementations.

Comment: What do you mean with "follow the standard implementations"? What can I change to avoid the problem?

Comment: The standard implementation is that you should never try to block home-key effect. Because at any point, user should have the possibility to switch to main launcher by pressing the home-key. I think you should alter your application flow (design) to avoid the requirement of blocking home-key.